# Minification of vue project

Tags: vue.js, npm, minify, webpack-4, vue-cli-3

- I'm using vue: 2.6.10
- Project was generated using vue cli 3 https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/
- this vue cli contains some how webpack 4

I want to archive minification (removing all whitespaces, newlines, etc.) of sources of my project.
So instead 20mb i want to have ~4mb

My sources:

```
//file name package.json
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
...
}
```

My project contain:

- many *.vue files containing components which I have build.
- some *.js files

When I'm typing in my console:

```
npm run build
```

It runs script from above -> "build": "vue-cli-service build"

Everything runs and I end up with result:

[image]

What I've got:

[image]

and app.js file is very heavy ~20mb, I don't know where is **3.5mb** build.min.js file, how to force npm via this vue cli to archive this?

Maybe You know how decrease vue application from ~20mb to ~3.5mb?

Comment: The "Gzipped" column means the size of the dist/app.js file when the server sends it with gzip compression. It's not the size of any .min.js file.

Comment: A 20+mb payload? What kind of libraries are you importing? Are you using dynamic imports so that modules are only imported as of when needed?

Comment: @Terry I', importing vuetify library like this:
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' 
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

Comment: @JJJ ok but how to receive such .min.js file?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

Comment: As pointed out 20mb payload is something to worry about. Should definitely check out `Webpack bundle analyzer` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer). Gives you an overview of whats what.

Answer (score 0):

I have realised what i did wrong:

- it's worth to check webpack --version ( I had old one sudo apt get install webpack installed me 3.6.4 version on Ubuntu 19.04)
- I was trying use vue.config.js which wrapps webpack and this was not good idea something didnt work for me
- finally I've configured webpack.config.js for vue + vuetify which looks like this:

> ```
> const path = require('path')
>
> const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
> const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
> const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
> const JavaScriptObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');
>
> module.exports = {
>   entry: './src/main.js',
>   output: {
>     path: path.resolve(__dirname,
>         '../monitglass-backend/src/main/resources/static/js/app'),
>     publicPath: '/dist/',
>     filename: 'app.js'
>   },
>   plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()
>     , new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
>     , new TerserPlugin()
>     , new JavaScriptObfuscator({
>       identifierNamesGenerator: 'mangled'
>     })
>   ],
>   module: {
>     rules: [
>       {
>         test: /\.vue$/,
>         loader: 'vue-loader',
>         options: {
>           loaders: {}
>           // other vue-loader options go here
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         test: /\.css$/,
>         use: [
>           'style-loader',
>           'css-loader'
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         test: /\.js$/,
>         loader: 'babel-loader',
>         exclude: /node_modules/
>       },
>       {
>         test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
>         loader: 'file-loader',
>         options: {
>           name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
>         use: [
>           'vue-style-loader',
>           'css-loader',
>           {
>             loader: 'sass-loader',
>             options: {
>               implementation: require('sass'),
>               fiber: require('fibers'),
>               indentedSyntax: true // optional
>             }
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     ]
>   },
>   optimization: {
>     minimizer: [
>       new TerserPlugin({
>         terserOptions: {
>           ecma: undefined,
>           warnings: false,
>           parse: {},
>           compress: {},
>           mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
>           module: false,
>           output: null,
>           toplevel: false,
>           nameCache: null,
>           ie8: false,
>           keep_classnames: undefined,
>           keep_fnames: false,
>           safari10: false,
>         },
>       }),
>     ],
>   },
> }
> ```

So on the end of the day I'm finishing with app.js  3.82 MiB minified and obfuscated. I hope this post will help others who will look for such answer.